# How to enable caching for ajax callbacks, especially for colorbox node?

Tags: ajax, caching, performance, javascript

I am using [colorbox node](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox_node) module on my site, and it looks like the ajax callbacks for rendering the node are not cached at all. Tested it with a simple snippet in the node template:

```
<div>generated on <?php $dt=new DateTime();print $dt->format('d.m.Y H:i:s');?></div>
```

Colorbox is using a custom display, to have a custom node.tpl

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['node']->type == 'my_content_type' && $vars['view_mode'] == 'colorbox') {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__my_content_type__colorbox';
  }
}
```

Caching for anonymous user is turned on and works for node pages.

is this issue related to colorbox node (e.g. missing caching implementation in colorbox node) or some other module?

I dived into the code of colorbox node and found out that the click on a colorbox link will be rewritten and rerouted through this menu:

```
/*
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function colorbox_node_menu() {
  $items['colorbox/%colorbox_node_url'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'colorbox_node_output',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'load arguments' => array('%map'),
    'delivery callback' => 'ajax_deliver',
    'theme callback' => 'ajax_base_page_theme',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

is there a way to cache `'delivery callback' => 'ajax_deliver',` without hacking the `colorbox_node_output()` function? Whats the best practice here to get this into caching? I think implementing a cache inside `colorbox_node_output()` might already be too late because it is running through the complete bootstrap process before executing that function.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done. Will require 2 hooks [hook_menu_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) & [hook_boot()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_boot/7) and some non trivial code.

Top level overview of how to do this:
Use hook_menu_alter() to call a wrapper around colorbox_node_output() that will cache its output. Use hook_boot() to check the cache and deliver the cached content, routing the cached content though [ajax_deliver()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/function/ajax_deliver/7).

An example of cache code flow can be seen in the 6.x-2.x [ESI](http://drupal.org/project/esi) module. [esi_get_page_cache()](http://drupalcode.org/project/esi.git/blob/dcc9036f7f1f37e8e485629895c69d75b882111b:/esi.module#l792) gets called from esi_boot. [esi_set_page_cache()](http://drupalcode.org/project/esi.git/blob/dcc9036f7f1f37e8e485629895c69d75b882111b:/esi.module#l732) is what sets the cache; you can see it getting called at the bottom of these functions: [esi__block_handler()](http://drupalcode.org/project/esi.git/blob/dcc9036f7f1f37e8e485629895c69d75b882111b:/esi.module#l366) & [esi__panel_pane_handler()](http://drupalcode.org/project/esi.git/blob/dcc9036f7f1f37e8e485629895c69d75b882111b:/esi.module#l518). Side note: A big reason the ESI module's cache code has a lot of complexity is it's compatible with D6 core and Pressflow; both have different code for the page cache.

Comment: thanks for the input. I already looked deeply into it. and tried/ glued it together with drupal.org/project/js but, now one of the main problems here: ajax_deliver needs for whatever reasons a full bootstrap. I will answer this question with the total results of my research as soon as Ive completed it.

Comment: I would have guessed otherwise given the comments in the code for [ajax_footer](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/function/ajax_footer/7). In that case do everything that ajax_deliver does, expect for ajax_footer and cache that.

Comment: thats the plan :) got it on my road map, but the solution isnt that trivial, there's pretty much data exchange within ajax_deliver and drupal's core like session stuff. I have to find out whats important for colorbox in that case. I will post an answer as soon as I had time for that.